# Grep/bash regex - combination of alternation and set of numbers

Tags: regex, bash, grep, githooks

I need to end up matching any of the following:
`AD-123, ad-123, AD123, and ad123`

So far what I have is

`| grep -oP 'AD-|ad-|AD|ad'[0-9]\+)`

but that only matches the letters and completely ignores the numbers, and I can't figure out a bash-friendly way to do this.

Context/use case: prepare-commit-msg githook, I want to take the Jira ticket from the branch name and add it to any commit message. The Jira ticket would be written in one of the ways described above under a branch naming convention of feature/version/ticker-keywords (example feature/1.1.3/ad-123-some-branch)

Comment: `grep -oE '(AD|ad)-?[0-9]+'`? Or `grep -oE "(AD|ad)[-']?[0-9]+"`?

Comment: Try `(?:AD|ad)-?\d+`

Comment: `| grep -oE "(AD|ad)[-']?[0-9]+"` works, thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55355721/3832970).

Comment: Remember `grep` is not part of the standard `bash` shell. They are external binaries packed along with the OS. If you are not looking for the built-in `bash` utilities for this remove the string from the title and the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
| grep -oE "(AD|ad)[-']?[0-9]+"
```

This is a POSIX ERE (due to `-E` option) regex that matches

- `(AD|ad)` - either `AD` or `ad` (not `aD` or `Ad` since that is not allowed as per your requirements)
- `[-']?` - an optional `-` or `'`
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits

Visualization:

[image]